# Entity Framework with code first connects to database even if I use IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to create entity framework **code first** scenario with **existing database**. 
The problem is that when I run the program it *tries to connect to database even if I use `IQueryable<>`*. Please, read my *comments inside the code* for more details:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SomeContext db = new SomeContext())
    {
        // This one does not connects to database. 
        // If I disable my network connection this code will still be executed
        IQueryable<Activity> allActivitiesQuery = db.ActivitySet;

        // This one does connects to database. 
        // If I disable my network connection this query will throw exception
        IQueryable<Activity> filteredActivitiesQuery = db.ActivitySet
            .Where(activity => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.FirstProperty));
    }

    //If I use same context again it will not connect to database
    using (SomeContext db = new SomeContext())
    {
        //Both statements will be executed even network connection is closed
        IQueryable<Activity> allActivitiesQuery = db.ActivitySet;
        IQueryable<Activity> filteredActivitiesQuery = db.ActivitySet
            .Where(activity => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.FirstProperty));
    }
}
```

How can I prevent this behaviour? When I used **database first and generated my models from database** this did not happen.
How can I prevent connection request to database when I use just `IQueryable<>`?

---

**Additional details:**

***In case you need them***, here are my models:

```
//model
public class Activity
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public string SecondProperty { get; set; }
    public string ThirdProperty { get; set; }
}

//mapping details
public class ActivityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Activity>
{
    public ActivityMap()
    {
        //Primary key
        ..........

        //Properties
        .............

        //Table & column mappings 
        .......................
    }
}

//Context details
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    static SomeContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SomeContext>(null);
    }

    public SomeContext()
        : base("Name=SomeContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Activity> ActivitySet { get; set; }

    // Add mapping configuration for code first POCO objects
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ActivityMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from your problem/question: Why would you want to use EF/`IQueryable` without a working DB connection? About your problem: What command is EF trying to execute at that point?

Comment: @ChrFin I don't need it because of performance issues. I will check it myself. Will it every time check it, ot it is done one time at every run? It is not executing anything. Just generating query to get filtered data.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: @ChrFin 'A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network'. Please read my comments in code for more details

Comment: An IQueryable would not connect to the database unless you try to enumerate it (for loops, ToArray, etc). If it does try to reach the database, my guess would be there's an overlooked code that tries to materialize the IQueryable. Try enabling Intellitrace and see what sql command is being execute and try it backward to the code that initiated it.